# CSS Breadcrumb Layout

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I am attempting to create a breadcrumb (buttons followed by a single span) for the user to navigate a directory structure.  I would like to provide this in a horizontal layout with the following properties:

1. If there is enough space for all buttons/text, then show all buttons with the minimum width required to do so (e.g., the buttons are as slim as possible).
2. Once there is no longer space for all buttons/text, then begin collapsing only the buttons.  Preferably, this collapse would happen proportionally to each button's size.
3. Once all buttons have been collapsed to some min-width, then start collapsing the final span.

I have full control of both the DOM and CSS.  Here are screenshots of what I am looking to see in each case (ignore the vertical alignment and changing button margin issues):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how to accomplish the above layout in HTML 5?  Note that I only need to support modern browsers (IE/Edge support is **not** required).

Comment: sounds like a case for `flexbox`, in combination with `flex-shrink` --> cf. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-shrink/

Comment: Where's your markup? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #F00;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: horizontal;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div > * {
  min-width: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

span {
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

button {
  flex-shrink: 50000000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Button</button>
  <button>Long Button</button>
  <span>Post-Btn Text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to set `flex-shrink;` to `0` on the span.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid;
}

button {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 30px;
}

span {
  min-width: 50px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
Bottom right corner to resize.
<div>
  <button>Button</button>
  <button>Long Button</button>
  <button>Even longer Button</button>
  <span>Post-Btn Text</span>
</div>
```

---

Because the span must also shrink eventually it also needs at least `flex-shrink:1;`.

The issue with this is that the shrink value on the buttons must be really high enough so that the span doesn't shrink with the buttons and it can't be too high otherwise the buttons won't shrink.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid;
}

button {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 30px;
  
  flex-shrink:999999999999;
}

span {
  min-width: 50px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  
  flex-shrink:1;
}
```

```html
Bottom right corner to resize.
<div>
  <button>Button</button>
  <button>Long Button</button>
  <button>Even longer Button</button>
  <span>Post-Btn Text</span>
</div>
```

I might come back to this see if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to resize the window. I hope it helps.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px red solid;
}

.container button,
.container span {
  font-size: 1rem;
  min-width: 30px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>Button</button>
  <button>Long Button</button>
  <button>Longer Batton</button>
  <span>Some Text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution begins collapsing the span in conjunction with the buttons once the width is too small, and therefore doesn't meet criteria #2: "Once there is no longer space for all buttons/text, then begin collapsing only the buttons".

Comment: OK, I'll think a little bit about how to fix this.